# Objective-C modifiers question

Tags: objective-c, ios

In objective C, in my header files, I often do this:

```
@private
NSString *h1;

@private
NSString *str;
```

But would that be the same as simply doing:

```
@private
NSString *h1;
NSString *str;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes they are functionally equivalent. The first example is just a waste of space.

Comment: +1 And also a waste of compile time, RAM, and CPU and hard disk life time.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they are the same. Per the documentation: [The Objective-C Programming Language](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocDefiningClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH12-TPXREF127)